# Google script onedit does not work for referenced cells

Tags: google-sheets

I have cells that have an if statement linked to a different sheet using importrange. However, when the status changes to "YES" on my sheet, the onedit script which logs time and date does not run.

However when I manually type "YES" the script successfully logs time and date.

Is there a workaround or an alternative to onEdit to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnEdit` trigger doesn't care if value, returned by formula, changes. It will react only if different value or formula will be entered.

You may use [Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions).

Comment: Thanks Max. I got around this problem by logging the timestamp on the source sheet and referencing it to the working sheet. Long way round, but solves the problem as I needed the log to be exact  to the point of change. But thanks, the time-driven trigger will help me with one other problem I am having (which I never knew existed before).